# php preg_replace question mark ("?") - not working

Tags: php, regex

I have a string

```
$name = "name1?name2?name3?name4";
```

I want to modify this variable as

```
$name2 = "name1/name2/name3/name4";
```

using php [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/preg_replace).

How can I do this?

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried already?  Your question title and tagging implies you've taken a few shots at the problem, but your question seems entirely devoid of code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to escape the `?` with `\`

```
<?php
$string = 'name1?name2?';
$pattern = '/\?/';
$replacement = '/';
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
?>
```

**Time to test...**

*I stand by my answer, as it answered the OP's question most directly. But my speed comment was not accurate - at all. The differences I found are easy to see, but weren't that impressive* IMO.*

**The Benchmark:** I took the OP's string and concatenated it 500000 times - so each function would have plenty of replacements to do (1.5- or 2-million depending).

Here are the functions and their speeds:

```
str_replace('?', '/', $test); // name1/name2/name3/name4/
0.388642073
0.389673948
0.385308981

preg_replace('/\?/', '/', $test); // name1/name2/name3/name4/
0.812348127
0.812065840
0.819634199

$bad = array('1?','2?','3?');
$good = array('1/','2/','3/');
str_replace($bad, $good, $test); // name1/name2/name3/name4?
0.712552071
0.725568056
0.718420029

preg_replace('/\?(\w+\d+)/', '/$1', $test); // name1/name2/name3/name4?
1.515372038
1.516302109
1.517566919
```

So...I lose. This testing showed str_replace() to be ***2X faster*** than preg_replace(). But, 1.5 seconds vs 0.7 seconds (last two functions) isn't bad when you consider all 1.5 million replacements are finished - not to mention the last one will resolve many more combinations than its competitor.

Don't you want the celebratory fist-pump when you write that perfect RegEx function? :-)

Comment: preg_replace() is faster than str_replace()

Comment: do you have the figures to back up your statement that preg_replace() is faster than str_replace(). It contradicts what most people say about the two.

Comment: @Mark - thanks. I now know waaay to much about the available string replacement functions. I'll add the test data to my post.

Comment: Thanks for actually going away and doing those tests, a +1 for making the effort. preg_replace() will always be slower than str_replace(), even for the most simple of replacements... it's strength lies in its flexibility, and its ability to handle far more complex and sophisticated replacements. If you want some more fun, strtr() should be even faster than str_replace() for this simplistic replacement (it would still work in the OP's case), but is even less flexible (single character replacements only, though at least it can work with a list of single characters, and not binary-safe)

Comment: I had to escape with `"\?"`

Answer (score 8):

You can easily do with [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php). I don't think there is a need of preg family

```
$name2=str_replace("?","/",$name)
```

Comment: `str_replace` is a simple string search and replace. `preg_replace` uses a form of regular expressions called PCRE, thus it's a lot more powerful - but also slower.

Answer (score 1):

You can use str_replace, just like @Shakti said.

Or, if you insist on doing it with preg_replace, you can do like this:

```
$name2 = preg_replace("|\?|", "/", $name);
echo $name2;
```

The difference between str_replace and preg_replace is, preg_replace do replacement using regex. And, on regex, character `?` has special meaning. In order to make it meaningless to preg_replace, you have to escape it using `\`.

For more information, go, read each function's description on PHP manual:

- [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)
- [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

Comment: i got it.. thanks.. really useful.. I used `preg_replace("/?/", "/", $name);` and it failed.. do u know the reason??

Comment: you forgot to escape `?`. It has special meaning on regex (which is what's used by preg_replace). In order to make it meaningless, you have to escape it, by using `\`